# extract grammar features from sentence on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, antlr3, nlp

For my GAE app I need to do some natural language processing to extract the subject and object from an input sentence.

Apparently [NLTK can't be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286301/using-the-python-nltk-2-0b5-on-the-google-app-engine) (easily) on GAE so I am looking for another solution.
I noticed GAE comes with [Antlr3](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Antlr) but from browsing their documentation it solves a different kind of grammar problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily build and NTLK RPC server on some machine and access it.

Another option is to find another web based service that already does that (such as opencalais).

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the NLTK problem specifically, my solution would probably be to fix the weird imports that NLTK is doing, and use that as originally planned.  When you're done, submit a patch of course.

That said, if this ultimately involves touching the data store, the answer is that it probably can't be done in a performant way, unless your data set is small or for some reason your NLP stuff doesn't need to hit some kind of full-text index.  The [GAE guys are working on it](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=217), but they have indicated that no one should be expecting a quick resolution to this particular issue.