# Python - importing a module from same directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using the Python NLTK (2.0b5) on the Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286301/using-the-python-nltk-2-0b5-on-the-google-app-engine)

I was adding my script to the Google App Engine and I needed to get some modules to work. So I found the plain old file (in my case "NLTK" module) and I added it to the same directory as my Google App Engine project. Currently all my errors are coming from the importing of nltk, and when I try it completely ignoring the google app enging by testing it in another file I still get an import error.

So how can I import the NLTK module when it is in a folder in the same directory as my python file without getting an error.

**Edit:**
So I got the import line to work in IDLE...

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

But I still get a server error when trying to use the program with Google app engine

Comment: When I try it with google app engine I get a "Server error" when I uncomment the line trying to import NLTK. When I use a test file (that I test in IDLE) to try and successfully import the module I get an "import error"

Comment: you should check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286301/using-the-python-nltk-2-0b5-on-the-google-app-engine , looks like a very similar question

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://code.google.com/p/nltk-gae/)?

Comment: "Server error" is completely useless for debugging. What does the traceback in the log say?

Comment: re @Jeff's reference:  The NLTK has changed a lot since 2009-- not to mention the GAE. I don't know what the real problem was back then, but there's a good chance that things have changed since.

Comment: yes I looked at it, thank you it help (sorta, I am gonna have to put more code in down the line. I blame nltk)

Comment: how do I check the traceback log

Answer (score 0):

This question is too vague, you need to include more details.

It sounds like you're trying to include nltk in your GAE project and you've copied one file into your GAE project folder.

You'll need to include the entire nltk folder in your GAE project.  If there are any other dependencies that nltk requires, you'll need to include those in your GAE project too.

Comment: I did add the whole folder (at least I think I did)