# Javascript+Python: sending array to Python script, returning result to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, nltk

I would like to set up a webpage that takes a number of Facebook status updates via the Javascript API and sorts them into an array. Then I'd like to send this array to a Python script, which can specifically do language analysis with [NLTK.](http://nltk.org/) After I get a suitable result in Python, I'd like to return the result from that script to Javascript for displaying to the user, etc. Does this sound possible?

Comment: Why don't you just use json?

Comment: Use json for what? With NLTK? Does that work?

Comment: Use json for communicating between Python and JavaScript.

Comment: I meant you can simply parse the Javascript API result using the json module in the standard library, which will return a python object which you can then presumably use in NLTK

Comment: Any resources showing how to do that with an array would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, totally. Check out Google App Engine to build this sort of functionality.
In particular check out these links:

NLTK on App Engine: [Using the Python NLTK (2.0b5) on the Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286301/using-the-python-nltk-2-0b5-on-the-google-app-engine) and http://code.google.com/p/nltk-gae/

Facebook API on App Engine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/shelftalkers

I assume that you want to make it interactive because you mentioned the word "user".

Comment: You don't _need_ to use the App Engine for this sort of thing - although it's one possibility. Fundamentally, this is a very common problem and can be summed up by considering the NLTK part of the process as an API. You could then call it using Ajax

Comment: True; I listed one of the most common options.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a service from Javascript is a very common problem. One way of solving it is to write a specific type of website known as a Webservice which would make the process flow something like...

- Javascript uses Ajax (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) to send an HTTP Request to your Webservice containing the information you want to process.
- The Webservice receives the request and performs the requested processing (eg by invoking the NLTK)
- The resulting data is sent back over the same Http connection
- A javascript function is called and passed the results of the data

The easiest way to send a request is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). The easiest way to format the data to be passed back and forth is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation).

An example call would look something like this...

```
$.json({
  url: "/url/of/Webservice",
  data: {
         "SomeKey": "SomeValue",
         "SomeList": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
         /*... etc */
        }
}).done(function(response) {
  //Assuming a response that looks like this: {"Result": "Some Result"}
  alert("The Webservice said: " + response.Result);
});
```

It's up to you how you'd implement the Webservice. If you want to use Python, [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is one of many good frameworks to get you started